# How to solve the problem with read apache mllib demo file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and I am trying to run the following code that comes from the Apache Spark MLlib guide locally on a Mac. I have installed Java 8, Scala, spark and pyspark. Scala and pyspark work on the terminal.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)

from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

# Load training data
training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("sample_libsvm_data.txt")
```

The file is in the project folder but I get the following error:

```
    training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("sample_libsvm_data.txt")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-16efb76d78dc>", line 1, in <module>
    training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("sample_libsvm_data.txt")

  File "/Users/georgioskourogiorgas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 166, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))

  File "/Users/georgioskourogiorgas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

  File "/Users/georgioskourogiorgas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)

  File "/Users/georgioskourogiorgas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o521.load.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
```

The file is not corrupt or empty.

Comment: Is it possible to have a reproducible example ? In it's actual state, your question isn't salvageable.

Comment: You can find the data file in:
https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/data/mllib

Comment: What version of spark are you using ? I can't reproduce the error you've mentioned on 2.3.2

Comment: The version I am using is 2.3.1 is there Athens wrong with my installation you think?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
First it needs a path for some reason. Although, I had created a project in Spyder it didn't recognise the working directory.
Then my path had a folder with a space. It didn't like that either.